# JavaScript show checkboxes onclick but first time not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show some checkboxes onclick event but the problem is when I clicked first time nothing happened, but every next click on the button running well..

I tried some scripts and ways (for example to append `return false;` to the `onclick=""` event in button) which I found on internet but anything I found does not working for me as I expected.

The button which have to trigger the function:

```
<button id="brandbutton" type="button" class="button">FILTROVAT DLE VÝROBCE &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

And the JavaScript snippet:

```
<script>
jQuery($ => {
  $('#brandbutton').on('click', () => {
    var html = "<?php echo get_some_tags_man(); ?>";
    $("#someID").html(html).toggle();
    $checkboxes = jQuery("input.brand:checkbox");
    $checkboxes.change(function(){
      window.location.search = '?product_tag=' + $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;   
      }).get().join(",");
    });
  });
});
  
</script>
```

Comment: Classic question. You attach the `.change()` (or `.click()`) listener _inside_ another function. It means that `brandButton()` has to be executed once for the listeners to be attached and start listening to click events, and _then_ they work.

Comment: @JeremyThille I changed my code but problem still persists.. Any advices, please?

Comment: You have changed your code... how?

Comment: @JeremyThille As you can see in this (edited) post. :)

Comment: Well nothing has changed. `$checkboxes.change` is still inside `$('#brandbutton').on('click')`, so you need first to click on `#brandbutton` to attach the change listener to the checkboxes.

Comment: @JeremyThille So, if I put `$checkboxes.change` outside the `$('#brandbutton').on('click')` then it still doing nothing and when is checkboxes variable is outside then does not working the adding url parameter to the url..

Comment: Well, now you have a `onclick="brandButton()"` handler, but no `brandButton()` function, so you probably get `Error : brandButton is undefined` in your console and your code crashes on click, doesn't it? Also, you have two different click handlers : one inline and another one with jQuery `$('#brandbutton').on('click')`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot update the code again, I trying and I also tried maybe everything, actually code is in edited post, but I don't know where is the problem, any ideas?

Comment: Yes I have an idea, I told you twice already, but the problem remains : _$checkboxes.change is inside $('#brandbutton').on('click')_ and still is, even after your latest code update. _PUT $checkboxes.change OUTSIDE $('#brandbutton').on('click')_

Comment: Your idea isn't helped me... I solved it, I forgot to add `display: none` to the #someID form. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you've nested the jQuery `change` event handler for your checkboxes within the function called `onclick` of the button. This means that when you first click the button the `change` event is only *bound* to the checkboxes. On the next click the event handler is bound again and the previous instance runs.

To fix this, and correct the issue of repeated event handlers, bind the checkbox event handlers using a single delegated event handler outside of the button click. Also move the button click handler in to a unobtrusive event handler, not in the HTML.

Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#brandbutton').on('click', () => {
    var html = "<?php echo get_some_tags_man(); ?>";
    $("#someID").html(html).toggle();
  });

  $('#someID').on('change', 'input.brand:checkbox', e => {
    window.location.search = '?product_tag=' + $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get().join(",");
  });
});
```

```css
#someID {
  display: none;
}

#brandbutton {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<button id="brandbutton" type="button" class="button">
  FILTROVAT DLE VÝROBCE &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i> 
</button>
```

Also note that the `html()` call on click of the button could be optimised by performing that call only once when the page loads, assuming that the content never changes - which it appears not to given the context of the example.

Comment: Hello, I tried to replace my JS with your Jquery but it not works for me still (problem persists), you can see and try it here: https://proairsoft.cz/airsoftove-zbrane/